# Involution-like functional equation $f(f(x))=ax+b$

Tags: functional-equations, involutions

Consider the following functional equation:
$$f(f(x))=ax+b$$
where $f$ is defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Questions:

1. If $b \neq 0$, what are the solutions?
2. If $a=1, b =0$ (ie. $f$ is an involution on $\mathbb{R}$), although $f(x)=\frac{1}{kx} (\text{where } k>0)$ is a solution on the domain $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, I wonder if we insist $f$ must be well-defined **on the whole $\mathbb{R}$**, would the only possible solutions left be linear functions of form $g(x)=cx+d$.

Comment: There are many solutions even for $f(f(x)) = x$. For example: $f(x) = 1-x$ if $0 \le x \le 1$, $f(x) = x$ otherwise. Or $f(x) = 1-x$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x) = 17-x$ otherwise.

Comment: Given any solution $f$ of $f(f(x)) = x$ and an invertible function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $g^{-1} \circ f \circ g$ is also a solution.

Comment: Thanks! What's the common practice on StackExchange when your question has been answered in the comments? Delete the question or leave it here?

Comment: You can request that the author of the comment copy it as a brief answer, or post it yourself as an answer. There are several questions over on meta about this sort of thing, e.g. [Dealing with answers in comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments)

Comment: @MartinR Hi, may I ask if you could post your comment as a brief answer? So that I could close this question.

Comment: For 1., if you assume $f$ is a polynomial and $a\geq 0$ then you get $f(x) = \sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}+1}$.